# Fn+F5,F6 keys to adjust brightness doesn't work

Tags: brightness, function-keys

I have an Asus N56JK computer and I have tried many different options such as updating the `Grub` file in `/etc/default/grub` but to no avail. All other Function keys seems to be working but only function keys used to adjust brightness are not working?

Comment: This should not have anything to do with Ubuntu. This should be specific to your laptop. Therefore, a manual specifically for your Asus N56JK should be the best approach. Still it would be interesting to know, have you already tested the Fn keys within Windows?

Comment: Yes it works as it should on Windows, only Ubuntu where it does not.

Comment: Try the Brightness-settings within System Settings. It's the symbol with the black monitor and a lock within the screen. You can set the brightness there manually.

Comment: You may as well check the Keyboard within the System Settings. Within that window you have two tabs. The right one leads you to the Hotkey settings.

Answer (score 12):

I have a Asus X551MA, here is what worked for me.

**Update Grub;**

1. Open `terminal` with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`
2. type in `terminal`;
   `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
3. Change;
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
   to
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi="`
4. `Save` and `Exit` `gedit`
5. type in `terminal`;
   `sudo update-grub`
6. `Restart` your computer; *(Don't forget to bookmark this page)*
   `sudo shutdown -r now`
   This should fix your issue, if not keep reading.

**Create 20-intel.conf**; *Intel GFX card only!*

1. Open `terminal` with `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`T`
2. type in `terminal`;
   `cd /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d`
3. now;
   `sudo touch 20-intel.conf`
4. then type;
   `gksudo gedit 20-intel.conf`
5. `Copy` & `Paste` the following lines into the document;

   ```
   Section "Device"
       Identifier "card0"
       Driver "intel"
       Option "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
       BusID "PCI:0:2:0"
   EndSection
   ```
6. `Save` and `Exit` the document.
7. `Restart` your computer;
   `sudo shutdown -r now`
   This should work, if not keep reading.

**Install 3.16 kernel for 14.04 LTS;**

1. Update;
   `sudo apt-get update`
2. Install;
   `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-utopic`

That's all I got, sorry if this is incompatible with your set-up as there may be additional steps required, and I prefer to refrain from giving blind advice. I do recommend upgrading the kernel however, as this may be the solution you need, if you are using Ubuntu 14.10 or later there is no need to upgrade the kernel.

Comment: I have the ASUS UX305CA (Intel m3, Skylake graphics) and confirm this worked perfectly.

Comment: Asus X550LN, Debian 8.6 @ linux3.16 - worked already after updating GRUB. Mighty thanks!

Comment: No result for Asus X541UJ.

Answer (score 7):

I have an ASUS UX305FA zenbook and the above suggestions re: messing around with /etc/default/grub ddidn't work for me.

This worked for me:
https://github.com/thezerobit/asus-zenbook-ux305fa

Install xbacklight

```
sudo apt-get install xbacklight
```

In Keyboard settings, set up custom shortcuts to increase or decrease backlight by calling `xbacklight -inc 10` or `xbacklight -dec 10`.

Edit: I own this laptop too and the xbacklight workaround does work. you should just not use the fn + f5/f6 buttons but use other keys, mine are ctrl + f3/f4. Also if i decrease too much, the screen will go entirely black..

Comment: I've set the shortcut keys to just F5 and F6, which is similar to how a macbook operates and so far I haven't had any problems :)

Comment: Tried on UX305CA, didn't work for me =[

Comment: On June 2017 it worked great for my ASUS UX360C