# Display brightness does not change on the fly

Tags: 16.04, display, brightness

My laptop, Acer Aspire 5740, running Ubuntu 16.04 and Windows 10 as dual boot.  On Windows I can change the display brightness so that it changes instantly, but when I boot into Ubuntu and change the display brightness, it doesn't change the brightness until I reboot. What may be the reason for this? How to fix it?

Comment: Have you resolved the issue @Nuwan ?

Comment: Possible kernel compatibility problem. Have you tried [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/594068/fnf5-f6-keys-to-adjust-brightness-doesnt-work)?

Comment: @lamino No I didn't. Thanks for the link. I can use Fn+ dedicated keys to adjust brightness, it show the brightness bar increasing and decreasing, but the adjustment take into effect after a reboot.

Answer (score 0):

try this to increase and decrease screen brightness

```
xrandr --current # to get the name of the your laptop's active display
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 1.0 # change from 0.0 to 1.0
```

Comment: should i change it through command line always?

Comment: What you think the reason for my problem?

Comment: No, you can use custom keyboard shortcuts to assign different commands as shown below  https://s29.postimg.org/3l3g310g7/Screenshot_from_2016_12_21_10_23_21.png