# Fn + F1..12 key combinations don't work after upgrading to Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 16.10, eeepc, function-keys

I'm having a strange problem after upgrading my ASUS 1215N from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10 (Unity 7).

Basically only Fn + F1..F6 combinations worked properly, all Fn + F7..F12 didn't even showed up in `acpi_listen`.

I've tried modifying GRUB configuration file as suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594068/fnf5-f6-keys-to-adjust-brightness-doesnt-work), adding `acpi_osi=` and most important keys now work, but there are still glitches.

Follows a resume of `acpi_listen` events when pressing each key combination, highlighting those not working.

I haven't tried creating *20-intel.conf* file because the netbook is equipped with two graphic cards and I'm not sure that that fix would work with the discrete one.

`acpi_backlight=vendor` creates more problem than it solves.

Last version of BIOS installed (0902).

---

`acpi_listen` results in this:

- Fn + F1: standby, works well

  ```
  button/sleep SBTN 00000080 00000000
  button/sleep PNP0C0E:00 00000080 00000001
  ```
- Fn + F2: toggle WiFi, ***no notification***

  ```
  # Was ON, turns OFF
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000010 00000000
  button/wlan WLAN 00000080 00000000 K
  -------------------------------------------
  # Was OFF, turns ON
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000010 00000001
  button/wlan WLAN 00000080 00000000 K
  ```
- Fn + F3: nothing assigned

  ```
  ^[OR
  ```
- Fn + F4: nothing assigned

  ```
  ^[OS
  ```
- Fn + F5, Fn + F6: brightness down / brightness up

  Used to work correctly before `acpi_osi=`, now it still works but ***no notification*** is shown on the desktop.

  Following an example going from brightness lowest to highest e backwards. As you can see brightness values range from `00000020` to `0000002a`.

  ```
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000020 00000041
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000020 00000042
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000021 00000007
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000022 00000008
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000023 00000007
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000024 00000006
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000025 00000006
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000026 00000006
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000027 00000006
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000028 00000006
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000029 00000006
  hotkey ASUS010:00 0000002a 00000037
  hotkey ASUS010:00 0000002a 00000038
  hotkey ASUS010:00 0000002a 00000039
  hotkey ASUS010:00 0000002a 0000003a
  hotkey ASUS010:00 0000002a 0000003b
  hotkey ASUS010:00 0000002a 0000003c
  hotkey ASUS010:00 0000002a 0000003d
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000029 00000007
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000028 00000007
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000027 00000007
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000026 00000007
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000025 00000007
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000024 00000007
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000023 00000008
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000022 00000009
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000021 00000008
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000020 00000043
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000020 00000044
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000020 00000045
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000020 00000046
  ```
- Fn + F7: turn display OFF, ***doesn't work*** in any configuration

  ```
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000016 00000000
  video/displayoff DOFF 00000089 00000000 K
  ```
- Fn + F8: switch video mode (presentation I guess), ***doesn't work*** thought I'm not sure what it should do

  ```
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000030 00000000
  video/switchmode VMOD 00000080 00000000 K
  ```
- Fn + F9: toggle trackpad, ***doesn't work*** (multiple press)

  ```
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000037 00000001
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000037 00000002
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000037 00000003
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000037 ........
  ```
- Fn + F10: mute, works now (multiple press)

  ```
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000013 00000001
  button/mute MUTE 00000080 00000000 K
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000013 00000002
  button/mute MUTE 00000080 00000000 K
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000013 00000003
  button/mute MUTE 00000080 00000000 K
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000013 ........
  button/mute MUTE 00000080 00000000 K
  ```
- Fn + F11, Fn + F12: volume down / volume up, works after `acpi_osi=`

  ```
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000014 0000002d
  button/volumedown VOLDN 00000080 00000000 K
  hotkey ASUS010:00 00000015 00000023
  button/volumeup VOLUP 00000080 00000000 K
  ```