# Some ACPI not working on ASUS T303UA

Tags: asus

I'm trying to use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on an ASUS T303UA laptop.

After I installed it I noticed that some of hotkeys do not work (`Fn+F5` and `Fn+F6` for brightness control, `Fn+F3` and `Fn+F4` for keyboard backlight control and etc.) but volume control (`Fn+F10`, `Fn+F11` and `Fn+F12`) work correctly.

I checked the output of `acpi_listen` and got the following for working keys and nothing for unworking ones.

> button/mute MUTE 00000080 00000000 K
>   button/volumedown VOLDN 00000080 00000000 K
>   button/volumeup VOLUP 00000080 00000000 K

Also I noticed that the `asus-laptop` kernel module is not loaded after I tried `lsmod | grep asus` and got the following result.

> asus_nb_wmi            24576  0
>   asus_wmi               28672  1 asus_nb_wmi
>   sparse_keymap          16384  1 asus_wmi
>   wmi                    20480  1 asus_wmi
>   video                  40960  2 i915_bpo,asus_wmi

Then I did `sudo modprobe asus-laptop` and got the error:

> modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'asus_laptop': No such device

I tried the answers for the following questions but it didn't solve.

- [Brightness fn key shortcut doesn't work on ASUS laptop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/471847/brightness-fn-key-shortcut-doesnt-work-on-asus-laptop)
- [Fn+F5,F6 keys to adjust brightness doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594068/fnf5-f6-keys-to-adjust-brightness-doesnt-work)

What should I do next? 
Any help would be appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

My current `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in `/etc/default/grub` is:

> GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="

I created `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` as follows:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "card0"
    Driver          "intel"
    Option          "Backlight" "intel_backlight"
    BusID           "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection
```

Comment: `asus-laptop` is for old laptops. Now `asus-nb-wmi` is used. The `acpi_osi=` should work.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thank you for your comment. I understood that `asus-laptop` is not needed here. I also tried `acpi_osi=` but it did not work. I edited my question to clarify that.

Comment: What is in your `/sys/class/backlight`? Does brightness change from System Settings?

Comment: @Pilot6 There're `acpi_video0` and `intel_backlight`. Yes, brightness changes from System Settings. Also it changes by writing to `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness`.

Comment: Did you create the `20-intel.conf` file?

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes. I added the content of the file.

Comment: Well, this means that Asus again has done something against the specifications. I suggest reporting it as a bug. Some tome the kernel developers will fix it, if they did not do it already in the newest kernels.

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks. I will try reporting and also upgrading kernels.

Comment: @FailyFeely Did you ever sort this out? I just bought a T303UA and have the same problem.  I have tried the methods mentioned here and updated kernel to 4.10.32, running Linux Mint 18.2