# Screen Brightness not staying at the brightness I selected

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, laptop, brightness

I have a problem with linux on my laptop, this problem has occurred on every single distro I have tried.

When I turn down my screen brightness with "fn + f5" it goes up and down a bunch for a minute or so. The only time this seems to not be the case is if I turned it too 100% Screen brightness or 0%, It will still say that it is changing and it will say 100% or 0% Brightness and i will hear the sound it makes when you switch brightness.

How do i fix this, so that i can change my screen brightness?

Comment: What GFX do in use? Do you try this mothod ? https://askubuntu.com/a/637842/550618

Comment: @ali76 Seemes To Have Worked When i changed GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash" to GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi=" in /etc/default/grub

Comment: I'm glad for your problem was solved, So I,ve posted this instruction as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to proxeIO [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594068/fnf5-f6-keys-to-adjust-brightness-doesnt-work/637842#637842), You can edit `/etc/default/grub` file:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

And change the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` line to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash pcie_aspm=force acpi_osi="`

Then run this command, that applies the changes:

```
sudo update-grub
```