# Hotkeys not working on login screen

Tags: login-screen, thinkpad

I came from windows 10 to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on my Thinkpad T440s. I can't seem to find out how to enable hotkeys to work on login screen (where you have to put password to login). None of the fn+f1...f12 combinaitons work.

Today was a sunny day, and I dualbooted to ubuntu, but could not see anything because yesterday I left my screen dimmed to minimum. I was not been able to login, because I simply could not see where to put my password in, nor been able to brighten my screen.
How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

My problem was partially solved by this thread:

[Fn+F5,F6 keys to adjust brightness doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/594068/fnf5-f6-keys-to-adjust-brightness-doesnt-work)

After updating GRUB and/or kernel, brightness fn controls started to work on login screen (however none of the other combinations work). I think I can live with that.